# How to dynamically discover endpoint

Tags: oauth, openid, openid-connect

I want to implement openid connect in my project. Right now I am hard coding the discovery url like for google - https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration , same for other source and then make this call and getting the endpoints for all the respective sources.
but I want to make it full dynamic. I found something on openid.net

```
GET /.well-known/webfinger
    ?resource=acct%3Ajoe%40example.com
    &rel=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fspecs%2Fconnect%2F1.0%2Fissuer
    HTTP/1.1
  Host: example.com

  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Content-Type: application/jrd+json

  {
   "subject": "acct:joe@example.com",
   "links":
    [
     {
      "rel": "http://openid.net/specs/connect/1.0/issuer",
      "href": "https://server.example.com"
     }
    ]
  }
```

How can I do this call. What should I placed in resouces, rel ?? I am beginner in oauth process. Could you plz help me out.

Answer (score 1):

very few of the major IdPs support dynamic registration. They all seem to want you to register on a web page where you can agree to their terms of use.

mojeid.cz is one I know that does. If you find others I would like to know.

I am coding up dynamic client now. It's tough. I do plan on posting it on GitHub at some point.   ..tom

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking Dynamic Registration is not necessarily coupled one-on-one with Discovery although typically it would be.

As the OP suggests, one can lookup the Provider's metadata through applying Webfinger Discovery as described in: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#IssuerDiscovery

The request and response would look as already presented in the question i.e. : http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#URLSyntax The RP can parse the "hreft" value from the response that would present the "issuer" value (i.e. a unique DNS bound identifier for the Provider) and then construct the well-known endpoint where the Provider's configuration metadata can be retrieved from as described here: http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderConfig

Assuming that the RP already has a `client_id`/`client_secret` established with that Provider in a previous out-of-bound step, this may avoid the RP having to store and/or cache the Provider's metadata.